# Why BitSet class and associated set method is used for?

Tags: java, bitset

Why we have `java.util.BitSet` class when do we use it in real time. and what does `set()` method do ? The `Java Doc` created a bit of confusion. Could anyone clarify?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This link should help :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333681/java-bitset-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The java.util.BitSet.and(BitSet set) method performs a logical AND of this target bit set with the argument bit set. This bit set is modified so that each bit in it has the value true if and only if it both initially had the value true and the corresponding bit in the bit set argument also had the value true.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

      // create 2 bitsets
      BitSet bitset1 = new BitSet(8);
      BitSet bitset2 = new BitSet(8);

      // assign values to bitset1
      bitset1.set(0);
      bitset1.set(1);
      bitset1.set(2);
      bitset1.set(3);
      bitset1.set(4);
      bitset1.set(5);

      // assign values to bitset2
      bitset2.set(2);
      bitset2.set(4);
      bitset2.set(6);
      bitset2.set(8);
      bitset2.set(10);

      // print the sets
      System.out.println("Bitset1:" + bitset1);
      System.out.println("Bitset2:" + bitset2);

      // perform and operation between two bitsets
      bitset1.and(bitset2);

      // print the new bitset1
      System.out.println("" + bitset1);

   }
```

output:-

```
Bitset1:{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Bitset2:{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}
{2, 4}
```