# Large String of 1 and 0 to BitSet

Tags: java, string, bitset

I have a very large string ( 64 characters) containing 1s and 0s.
sample - 1001111111101010011101101011100101001010111000101111011110001000

All I want is to convert it into BitSet var containing the 1s and 0s in same positions
I am using the function -

```
private static BitSet fromString(String binary) {
        return BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { Long.parseLong(binary, 2) });
}
```

and have already gone through  - [Java BitSet Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333681/java-bitset-example)
I have actually figured out the issue and that is my 64th bit being 1 and the function throwing up a number format exception
I have tried plethora of other conversions but can't get it working
Any help here would be appreciated
Thanks!!!

Comment: 64 bits is pushing it with `long`. Did you try this conversion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18925602/14955 ?

Comment: If you are using java8, you can do `Long.parseUnsignedLong()` and it should work fine..

Answer (score 7):

Since you have a string, contatining 0s and 1s only, you can simply do it without casting to Long, just using `String#charAt()` and [BitSet#set()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#set%28int%29). For example, like so:

```
private static BitSet fromString(String binary) {
    BitSet bitset = new BitSet(binary.length());
    for (int i = 0; i < binary.length(); i++) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            bitset.set(i);
        }
    }
    return bitset;
}
```

Or with r-l orientation, as it usually used:

```
private static BitSet fromString(String binary) {
    BitSet bitset = new BitSet(binary.length());
    int len = binary.length();
    for (int i = len-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (binary.charAt(i) == '1') {
            bitset.set(len-i-1);
        }
    }
    return bitset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution using Stream API:

```java
final String s = "1001..." // the input string
final int n = s.length();
BitSet set = IntStream.range(0, n)
   .filter(i -> s.charAt(i) == '1')
   .collect(() -> new BitSet(n), (t, i) -> t.set(i) , (t1, t2) -> t1.or(t2));
```