# what is the purpose of BitSet valueOf in fromString method

Tags: java, api, bitset

I would appreciate an explanation of what this line does exactly.

```
BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { Long.parseLong(s, 2) });
```

While this code example posted by [FauxFaus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9334117/4177087) really helped me understand BitSet usage, I don't find the purpose of the above line or why.
here is the full example:

```
package com.tutorialspoint;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.BitSet;
public class TimeZoneDemo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BitSet bits1 = fromString("1000001");
    BitSet bits2 = fromString("1111111");
    System.out.println(toString(bits1)); // prints 1000001
    System.out.println(toString(bits2)); // prints 1111111

    bits2.and(bits1);

    System.out.println(toString(bits2)); // prints 1000001
}

private static BitSet fromString(final String s) {
    System.out.println(BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { Long.parseLong(s, 2) }));
    return BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { Long.parseLong(s, 2) });
}
private static String toString(BitSet bs) {
    return Long.toString(bs.toLongArray()[0], 2);
}
}
```

Please note that I can't comment on the original answer to ask the OP.

Comment: Why not have a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html#valueOf-long:A-).

Comment: Which part exactly are you having trouble understanding? Break it down into smaller pieces and focus your question on a particular problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Long.parseLong(s, 2)` parses the `String` `s` as a binary `String`. The resulting `long` is put in a `long` array and passed to `BitSet.valueOf` to generate a `BitSet` whose bits represent the bits of that `long` value.

The reason `BitSet.valueOf` takes `long` array instead of a single `long` is to allow creation of `BitSet`s having more than 64 bits.

Comment: Now it is very clear, thanks for helping a struggling beginner